# Sparse Checkout with Jenkins DSL Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Does anyone have a code sample for the correct

```
configure { ... }
```

block needed in the Jenkins DSL plugin to set up a git sparse checkout?

It appears as if the config.xml section looks like this:

```
<extensions>
  <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CloneOption>
    <shallow>false</shallow>
    <reference>/build/jenkins/codebase.git</reference>
  </hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CloneOption>
  <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPaths>
    <sparseCheckoutPaths>
      <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath>
        <path>BillOfMaterials.yml</path>
      </hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath>
      <hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath>
        <path>jenkins/job/</path>
      </hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath>
    </sparseCheckoutPaths>
  </hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPaths>
</extensions>
```

Comment: You might have better success with the Jenkins Job-DSL groups page https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/job-dsl-plugin. Is that in the global Jenkins config?

Comment: Thanks, asking there too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
job('job1') {
    description 'sparse checkout example'
    scm {
        git {
            reference('/build/jenkins/codebase.git')
            configure { git ->
                git / 'extensions' / 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPaths' / 'sparseCheckoutPaths' {
                    ['mypath1', 'mypath2', 'mypath3'].each { mypath ->
                        'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath' {
                            path("${mypath}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I sadly now have no good way to test this, as I've decided on a different implementation strategy.... According to http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ this looks to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Current Jenkins / Job DSL versions allow producing multiple sparse checkout paths by specifying

```
        git {
          remote {
            url('ssh://...')
            credentials('...')
          }
          branch('*/master')
          extensions {
            sparseCheckoutPaths {
              sparseCheckoutPaths {
                sparseCheckoutPath {
                    path('path1')
                }
                sparseCheckoutPath {
                    path('path2')
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto the answer given by 'nbsp' I had to add the following bold keywords(enclosed within double asterisk if bold not visible) to get it working. Hope this helps someone. :)

```
configure { git ->
                git / 'extensions' / 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPaths' {
                      **sparseCheckoutPaths {**
                            sparseCheckoutPath.each { checkoutPath ->
                               'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SparseCheckoutPath' {
                                    path("${checkoutPath}")
                                }
                            }
                      **}**
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to create a folder with a shared library using DSL

```
folder("<your_folder_name_path>"){
            properties {
                folderLibraries {
                    libraries {
                        libraryConfiguration {
                            name("<your_shared_lib_name>")
                            implicit(true)
                            defaultVersion("<your_default_version>")
                            retriever {
                                scmSourceRetriever {
                                    scm {
                                        git {
                                            credentialsId("<credentials>")
                                            remote("<remote_url>")
                                            traits {
                                                cloneOptionTrait {
                                                    extension {
                                                        shallow( true )
                                                        noTags( true )
                                                        honorRefspec(true)
                                                        depth(1)
                                                        reference('')
                                                        timeout(10)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                sparseCheckoutPathsTrait {
                                                    extension {
                                                        sparseCheckoutPaths {
                                                            sparseCheckoutPath {
                                                                path("<my_sparse_checkout_path>")
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```