# How to use sparse checkout options using DSL

Tags: maven, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm not sure how to use sparsecheckoutpaths option in a DSL script. If I don't pass any argument then it works fine, but it's not working when I pass any argument, so I just need the sample code for using this option.

I tried to pass string, list but it's not taking any option.

> ERROR: (script, line 13) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.scm.GitExtensionContext.sparseCheckoutPaths() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [testValue]

Comment: This is the sample code  

mavenJob('jobname') {
    scm {
     git {
            remote {
                url('git url')
            }
        branch('develop')  
        extensions {
          sparseCheckoutPaths('need to pass some values in this')
        }
      }
     }        
     goals('clean package')
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can not configure sparsecheckoutpath directly via job dsl. You have to use the configure block like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688787/1564881).